# Trying to import and export AD groups from multiple workstations using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Trying to import and export AD groups from multiple workstations. I have a script that works and want to import a csv file and export a csv file with all the AD groups from each workstation.

Get-ADComputer w61707285 -Properties * | select Memberof -ExpandProperty Memberof

Answer (score 0):

If your input CSV file looks anything like this:

```
"WorkStation","Location","OtherInfo"
"w61707285","upstairs","blah"
"w12345678","downstairs","blahbla"
```

Then you want to import that file and get an array from the column that holds the computer names (in this demo that column is called `WorkStation`).
Loop through that array of computer names and for each of them get its property `MemberOf`.

*Do NOT use `-Properties *` if all you want is a few (in this case only one) extra property because it is time and memory consuming to ask for ALL properties*

Next, let the loop emit **objects** and capture the results in a variable.

To get the group **Name** instead of the **DistinguishedName** you have from the `MemberOf` property, you need `Get-ADGroup` aswell.

Finally, export this result to a new CSV file

Something like this:

```
$computers = (Import-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\ASComputers.csv').WorkStation
$result = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $computer.Name
            Group        = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $_).Name
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path $output -NoTypeInformation
```